# Flipping coins- percentages of heads vs tails

Tags: probability, statistics

If I flip a coin multiple times and count the number of time it fell on heads and the number of times it fell on tails and keep a track of them. In how many flips on average will the delta between percentage of heads and percentage of tails will be less than 0.1%?

Comment: I will rephrase the question- I want to check if a coin is fair(lands 50% of the times on each side. I assume that delta of 0.1% between them is fair). How many flips do i need in order to be 99% confident that the coin is fair?

Comment: It is not really a rephrasing, it is entirely different, and quite a bit easier.

Comment: Thanks Andre. So it is two questions i guess

Comment: For the second, it is well over a million.

Comment: @AndréNicolas can you show your calculation as an answer?

Comment: I cannot do that at this time.  It would not at all be an answer to the question as currently posed, it would be an answer to the very different question you asked in a comment. And if the original question were to change, and I knew it had changed, I could not answer it until morning, it is quite late here.

Comment: @AndréNicolas thanks. I posted it as a different question

Comment: The original question is quite interesting. There would be some initial inaccuracy using the normal approximation, but for the rest the method of indicator random variables would give a reasonably close answer. That question is about expectation rather than probabilities.

Comment: My reading of the original question is that a fair coin is flipped $n$ times giving $n$ observations of the cumulative $H$ and $T$ seen; then the number of times $\left|\frac{H-T}{H+T}\right| \lt \frac1{1000}$ is counted.  My calculations suggest that for $1$ flip, the expectation is $0$; for $10$ flips the expectation is about $1.71$; for $100$ flips about $7.04$; for $1000$ flips about $24.25$; for $10^4$ flips about $540.19$; for $10^5$ flips about $16663.55$; for $10^6$ flips about $483950.29$

Comment: The alternative rephrased question is at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1873620/checking-if-a-coin-is-fair

Comment: @AJ222: To be exact, are you asking for the number $n$ of trials such that if the coin has probability $1/2$ of landing heads, then with probability $0.99$ the ratio $\frac{|H-T|}{n}$ is $\lt 0.001$? If you want to calculate some other related probability, please be as clear as possible, so that I can give a precise answer in a comment.

Comment: In the above, $H$ is the number of heads, and $T$ the number of tails.

Comment: On the revised question, my calculations suggest that with a fair coin, $\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\frac{H-T}{H+T}\right| \lt \frac1{1000}\right) \approx 0.9900006$ for $n=6633001$ but about $0.989995$ for $n=6636000$, with any greater $n$ giving over $0.99$. Meanwhile a normal approximation (without continuity correction) of $(1000\Phi^{-1}(0.995))^2$ suggests $n \gtrsim 6634897$

Answer (score 1):

1) Interpreting the revised question as asking how many tosses $n$ of a fair coin are required to have the probability that $|H-T| \lt 0.001 n $ greater than or equal to $0.99$, where $H$ is the number of heads and $T$ the number of tails with $H+T=n$, this is equivalent to asking for $n$ such that $\mathbb{P}\left(-0.0005n \lt H-\frac12{n} \lt 0.0005n\right) \ge 0.99$ since if $H=\frac12{n}+0.0005n$ then $T=\frac12{n}-0.0005n$ and $H-T= 0.001n$.

It is typical to use a normal approximation to the binomial distribution for questions like this.  $H$ has a mean of $\frac12{n}$, a variance of $\frac14n$ and a standard deviation of $\frac12\sqrt{n}$.  So using $\Phi^{-1}$ as the inverse cumulative distribution function of a standard normal random variable, we have $\mathbb{P}\left(-\Phi^{-1}(0.995) \lt \dfrac{H-\frac12{n}}{\frac12\sqrt{n}} \lt \Phi^{-1}(0.995)\right) \gtrsim  0.99$ or  $\mathbb{P}\left(-\Phi^{-1}(0.995)\frac12\sqrt{n} \lt H-\frac12{n} \lt \Phi^{-1}(0.995)\frac12\sqrt{n}\right) \gtrsim 0.99$.

So we need to solve  $0.0005n \gtrsim \Phi^{-1}(0.995)\frac12\sqrt{n}$ which gives  $n \gtrsim (1000\Phi^{-1}(0.995))^2$ and since $\Phi^{-1}(0.995)\approx 2.575829$ this gives  $n \gtrsim 6634897$.

But this is only an approximation. We could use computer calculations of the binomial distribution to get exact answers, but there is an issue that due to rounding every thousand, the probability is not a monotonic function of $n$.  I believe that the smallest $\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\frac{H-T}{n}\right| \lt \frac1{1000}\right) \approx 0.9900006$ for $n=6633001$ but about $0.989995$ for $n=6636000$, with any greater $n$ giving over $0.99$.  So the normal approximation gives a reasonable answer.

2) The original question is actually slightly different, asking *"In how many flips on average will the delta between percentage of heads and percentage of tails will be less than $0.1\%$?"* Interpreting this as asking for the expected cumulative number of times in the $n$ tosses it is true that $\left|\frac{H-T}{H+T}\right| \lt \frac1{1000}$, it is possible to use linearity of expectation and to add up the probabilities of being in this interval.  For small values of $H+T$, it makes sense to use the binomial distribution as rounding matters: for example with $n \le 1000$ the probability is zero for odd $n$.

As I said in a comment while the question was closed, my calculations suggest that for $1$ flip, the expectation is $0$; for $10$ flips the expectation is ${2 \choose 1}\frac1{2^{2}}+ {4 \choose 2}\frac1{2^{4}}+ {6 \choose 3}\frac1{2^{6}}+ {8 \choose 4}\frac1{2^{8}}+ {10 \choose 5}\frac1{2^{10}}\approx   1.71$; for $100$ flips about $7.04$; for $1000$ flips about $24.25$; for $10^4$ flips about $540.19$; for $10^5$ flips about $16663.55$; for $10^6$ flips about $483950.29$.  For small $n$ the expected number is much smaller than $n$, but for very large $n$ most cases will fall in the relative small interval around the mean.

Answer (score -1):

Great question! So let's look at the binomial distribution. We can represent the standard deviation with the equation $\mu_x = \sqrt{npq}$ and $p$ in our case is the probability of heads. This is $.5$. Same with tails. $n$ is the number of tosses. So $\mu_x = \sqrt{.5 * .5 * n} = .5*\sqrt{n}$

Our mean here is zero and our standard deviation is $.5\sqrt{n}$. Because we can apply the same rules as the normal distribution, if we had, let's say $10,000$ tosses, 68% will fall within 1 standard deviation, so $.5\sqrt{10,000}$ which is $50$. For 99% confidence, we would do 3 standard deviations, so for this would be $150$. So we can be 99% confident that the difference is equal to or less than 150 tosses. You can apply this logic to your problem to get the answer.

Note: I'm not an expert in this field so please do feel free to edit anything that isn't proper terminology.

Comment: Thanks. Andre says it should be over 1million. Do you understand why?

Comment: @AJ222 ah yes, because you have to use what I gave you to solve the problem at hand. You can solve for n by doing some algebra and saying that .001 (.1%) times n equals 3 * .5 * sqrt(n). I got 2.25 million as a final answer. Does it make sense how I solved for n here?

Comment: My answer (see comments on the question) using a normal approximation would be about $(1000\Phi^{-1}(0.995))^2 \approx 6634897$

Answer (score -1):

> I want to check if a coin is fair(lands 50% of the times on each
>   side. I assume that delta of 0.1% between them is fair). How many
>   flips do i need in order to be 99% confident that the coin is fair?

For large n you can apply moivre laplace. So you approximate the binomial distribution by the normal distribution.

Let $p=\frac{X}{n}$, where $X\sim Bin(n,0.5)$. The equation becomes

$P(|\frac{X}n-0.5|\leq 0.001)=2\Phi\left(\frac{0.001}{ \frac{0.25}{\sqrt n}} \right)-1=0.99$

$\Phi\left(\frac{0.001}{ \frac{0.25}{\sqrt n}} \right)=0.995$

$\frac{0.001}{ \frac{0.25}{\sqrt n}} =\Phi^{-1}\left(0.995\right)$

$\frac{0.001}{ \frac{0.25}{\sqrt n}} =2.576$

$\sqrt n=2.576\cdot \frac{0.25}{0.001}$

$n=414,736$

Comment: Thanks. So is it 2m (see rb612's comment) or 400k?

Comment: From the result I got the number of tosses has to be at least $414.736$. Sure 2 million tosses is O.K. as well.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for the minimal number of course

Comment: You´re welcome.

Comment: If the  difference is to be $\lt 0.001$, the proportion of heads has to be between $0.4995$ and $0.5005$.

Comment: @callculus: In addition to the difference in interpretation of "the delta" there is a little problem with the $0.25$ of the answer. The standard deviation of the mean is $\frac{0.5}{\sqrt{n}}$, not $\frac{0.25}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas The stardardized random variable is $z_p=\frac{p-\pi}{\sqrt{\frac{p\cdot q}{n}}}$ Why  don´t you sleep ?

Comment: So you are suggesting that with $n=414736$ the probability of having $H-T$ between  $-414.736$ and $+414.736$ (i.e. $H$ between $207160.632$ and $207575.368$) is at least $0.99$.  I suspect that probability is closer to $0.48$

Comment: @Henry, my answer coincides with yours. If we use my equation and solve with the value provided, https://goo.gl/pGxuQT, we get a z-score of 1.28 (if I'm using my equation correctly) and this gives us around 80% probability.

Comment: @rb612: My answer (see comments on the question) using a normal approximation would be about $(1000\Phi^{-1}(0.995))^2 \approx 6634897$

Answer (score -2):

2. If I flip a coin "$2$" times... On average the delta between percentage of heads and percentage of tails will be less than $0.1 \%$. Thank you.

As It can be $\{HH \}$ or $ \{TT \}$ or $\{HT\}$ or $\{TH \}$

I went through a lot of sleeplessness because of this question randomly popping up somewhere I don't even remember now.

Comment: Not sure why this question just came alive again... but if you flip a fair coin twice, the difference between the percentage of heads and the percentage of tails is 100% with probability 1/2 and 0% with probability 1/2... so on average it is 50%.